# How to count how many times run a java file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Anyone know how to count: how many times was run a single java file in Eclipse?And write the timestamp of the executed file in a file.txt.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're asking? Are you trying to find out how many times a Java application has been launched?

Comment: It can't be difficult to write such a plugin, but why would you want one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the very easy way. Just use a .properties file. With it you are able to get and set one or more values. With that you are able to count the runs. Even if you want to count it for more classs or files!

To create a properties file, do it like so:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
```

Before you can get a value, you have to load the file, into your Properties variable:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
```

Than you have to set (or get) the value with a key, like:

```
prop.setProperty("classruncounter", "5");
```

or to get

```
prop.getProperty("classruncounter");
```

You can read more about [that](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) in that simple tutorial. I just give you a quick overview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one file to save the value of variable which indicates how many times you run file in eclipse and updated when you run file again.